# Создать несколько переменных из одной строки

Tags: php

Есть строка вида text1-text2-text3-text4

Нужно из неё задать значения переменным, сами значения разделены символом **-**

Должно получиться:

```
$a = text1;

$b = text2;

$c = text3;

$d = text4;
```

Как сделать?

Comment: explode() не подходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'text1-text2-text3-text4';
$arr = explode('-', $str);
list($a, $b, $c, $d) = $arr;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list($a,$b,$c,$d)=explode('-','text-text-text-text');
```